# single zero in z-domain transfer function calculatio

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I am designing a filter with two poles at DC and one zero at fs/10. For simplicity I choose fs=1; So my z-transfer function looks like: (z-z1)/(z-1)^2. Since z=exp(jwT)=cos(wT)+j*sin(wT). So if I want to place my zero at f=fs/10 then how I can calculate the value of z1?

Since it is a real value it doesnt have j*sin(wT) then I cannot use simply cos(wT)=fs/10. Please help in understanding how the real zero is calculated.
I have attached the matlab pole zero response of the function which say that z=0.533 will give me a zero at f=0.1*fs(My fs=1).

[image]

[image]

Regards

Comment: Have you tried writing the transfer function in `s` domain and then using a method to convert to `z` domain? Methods include bilinear transform, impulse invariance, matched pole-zero etc. Bilinear transform is usually preferred.

Comment: The number 0.533 may be arising from the transformation \$e^{-2\pi \frac{T}{10T}}\$ ? However, i still suggest the bilinear transform method to convert the whole filter in one go, rather than pole by pole and zero by zero. **Where will this filter be used** amd what are the required properties of the final implemented filter?

Comment: Please add the detailed steps used to create the discrete time filter in Matlab whose pole-zero map you have plotted.

Comment: Can you clarify your goal: do you need a system that has two poles at 1 and a zero at 0.1, or a system with two poles at 1 and a zero at 0.533?

Comment: I want a system with two pole at DC (f=0,z=1) and one zero at z=0.1fs.

Comment: @Sitward you cannot write `z = 0.1 fs`. The units don't match. The LHS is unitless (I think). The RHS has units of frequency. In the case of \$s = \sigma + j \omega\$, \$\omega\$ may have units of radian/s but does \$s\$ and \$\sigma\$ have units of rad/s ? Similarly for \$z = r e^{j\omega}\$, does z have units of frequency? I think there is some mismatch in the specification itself. Please tell us the actual requirements for the filter. Pole by pole, and zero by zero translation is **not** the usual method for digital filter design. You may think you want a zero with natural frequency ...

Comment: ... of -1 rad/s and zero damping, but what requirement of the system lead to that conclusion?

Comment: @ANJ you are right about the units but think about the circle in z-domain. when we say pole at z=1 then it means we are placing pole at f=0. Similarly when z=0.533 then we are placing a zero at f=0.1fs. When we say z=0.533 we are not at unit circle so we cannot say σ=0 in s=σ+jω. now z=r*e^(jw), w=0 so z=0.533

Comment: @AJN It's true that it's not the usual way, but it is often given as excercise. This is probably one of those cases, but OP needs to get a better translator. I'm not saying my English is superior, but I am saying that OP needs to get the message across. So far, from the question and all the comments, I'm getting more and more confused about OP's goal.

Comment: @Sitward Try this: draw by hand a picture of where the zero should be and mark it down with clear coordinates.

Comment: Let me me ask you another question. Below is pole zero plot of a matlab. How matlab draws the semi circle insidel the pz-map i.e. 0.1*pi/T or 0.8*pi/T? I have added the second picture in the question. These semi circle e.g. 0.2*pi/T represents where we will alwasy have pole/zero at 0.1*pi*fs. The answer to my original question lies where it cross  the axis (where i have a zero)?

Comment: Those come from the transformation \$z = e^{sT}\$. See a [sample code](https://pastebin.com/embed/fk080LbZ)

Comment: @Sitward Please don't change the subject. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. People don't want to sit and talk and talk. You have a question, people answer, that's how it works. So, please, either modify your question to reflect, *in clear*, what you are trying to achieve, or, if you have another question, post it as another question. But please don't presume people here are watching your progress and can't wait to reply to your comments. Either call a friend who speaks English better, or clear up your mind and make the question clear, so that you can receive a clear answer.

Comment: @AJN Thanks for the code

Comment: by the way I am a native English speaker and want to discuss to clear my concept. I have not changed the topic, my original question remain intact

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function based on poles and zeroes works just like in the *s*-plane, with proper adjustments for the *z*-plane: both the numerator and the denominator is built by using the product formula:

$$H(z)=K\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^M{1-a[k]z^{-1}}}{\prod_{k=1}^N{1-b[k]z^{-1}}} \tag{1}$$

In your case, since both their values are real, your zero is the value 0.1 (if that's what you want, a zero at one tenth of the sampling frequency). It should be clear that if using 0.533 in the numerator gives you a zero at 0.533, its value is that number.

What you're saying about the Euler's formula is related to evaluating the *z* in the frequency domain, but your business is with the zero, not *z*.

---

If I understand correctly, you need to have a pole **on the unit circle**, equal to \$0.1f_s\$. If this is true, then your only way to get that zero is by having a complex value, therefore:

$$z=\mathrm{e}^{j2\pi 0.1} \tag{2}$$

This means that your filter needs to be in quadrature, or you will need two signal paths. So, without knowing the purpose of your wanting to build such a filter, unless you can tolerate a complex valued zero, you can't have a zero on the unit circle anywhere else except at \$[-1,1]\$. That is, ***if*** I understood what you want, because it's verry fuzzy.

[image: test]

This is what the command `zplane([1 exp(-0.2i*pi)], [1 -2 1])` shows.

Comment: I think what the OP wants is know how to calculate 0.533 from the specification of a "*zero at 0.1fs*".

Comment: @AJN That's what I tried to explain. OP says he used the 0.533 value, and the picture shows the zero at 0.533. Therefore the value used is the actual zero. For 0.1*fs you need a 0.1, or the same way the pole is calculated: if it needs to be at 1, then it's 1. What I understand from OP is that he thinks he used the cosine to calculate the zero, but that only applies for a complex root, or evaluating *z* for magnitude response. It's possible I'm not on my best translator today, so I'll try to reformulate.

Comment: I understood OP's question as, "what procedure did Matlab use to say that a zero at 0.533 would show the frequency (in the tooltip in the figure) as 0.1rad/s?" I'm not sure though.

Comment: @AJN That's puzzling. The graph clearly shows the zero at 0.533, not 0.1, so using the value 0.533 is not the correct one if the zero needs to be at 0.1. Unless OP means to use exotic formulas that need to involve, somehow, 0.533 and cosine in order to get to 0.1, say `acos(0.1)/0.533`. But that would rather convoluted. Well, now I'm confused, I'll ask OP.

Comment: I meant solving for `x` in `cos(0.533*x)=0.1` there. So it comes out as `x=acos(0.1)/0.533`.

Comment: The matlab plot a zero at z=0.533. If I use s-domain then z=e^sT=(e^aT)(e^jwt). We know that w represent frequency which is zero here. So matlab equates e^(aT)=0.533. aT=ln(0.533) --> a/fs = ln(0.533). I am confused how I shall interpret a here? If I use also a=2*pi*f then f=0.1 which you see in matlab plot.

Comment: @Sitward You're overthinking this. Think of it this way: you wanted a pole at 1, therefore you wrote `z-1`. You needed two of them, so you wrote `(z-1)^2`. So then if you need a zero at 0.1, all you need is to apply the same thinking: `z-0.1`. That's it. That's all my answer tries to say: that both the numerator and the denominator are products of `z` minus the respective poles (`b[k]`) and zeroes (`a[k]`).

Comment: actually everything in z-domain translates into frequency. when we say pole at z=1 which actually mean that we have a pole at DC. Similarly I want a zero at 0.1fs so that my system nicely return to first order so that I dont face stability issues.

Comment: @Sitward There must be a language barrier, becuase I have no idea to what you're replying. I have already answered more than once what you need to do and why. But, as a last resort, here's your transfer function: $$H(z)=\dfrac{z-0.1}{(z-1)^2}$$This has a zero at 0.1 and a double pole at 1.